# Bind Jquery Array to ASP.NET MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have emp class with Id & Name properties

```
class Emp
{
   int id{get;set;}
   int Name{get;set;}
}

@model List<Emp>
<script>
    function convertJqueryModelToMVC()
    {
           var emps = [];
           emps.push({id:1,Name:"abc"});
           emps.push({id:2,Name:"xyz"});
           //logic for converting emps to List<emp> model
    }
</script>
```

I want to achieve this so that when i click on submit button all the form fields will be submitted in a single postback. This is just an example what i am trying to achieve 
(Note : I am aware standard MVC process)

Comment: Use WebAPI for that.

Comment: we dont use WebAPI in our project

Comment: Do you want to dynammically append values to your form & then want to submit it to server side?

Answer (score 1):

Pass Json Object from Javascript, The Model binder will automatically do its job. Like this.

```
var emps= [
        { id: 1, Name: 'name1' },
        { id: 2, Name: 'name2' },
        { id: 3, Name: 'name3' }
    ];      

    emps= JSON.stringify({ 'empList': emps});

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Employee',
        data: emps,
        success: function () {          
            $('#result').html('successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult Employee(List<Emp> empList)
{

//Your Logic

}
```

Comment: I dont want to make an AJAX call i want to send data on submit button

Comment: Then why you are constructing Javascript array in convertJqueryModelToMVC function ? How can you send the Javascript array to the controller with out using Ajax ?

Comment: I created dynamic hidden fields with name ="[0].Id" & "[0].Name" & i got the Model in HttpPost